# mounting data volumes to another container

Tags: mysql, docker

I used to have a zabbix container that died due  to reasons. It had a couple of data volumes in it located in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/XXX/_data` that now, I want to exist in the new container that I'm launching.

I figured if I start the container again with new mounts, It'll get fixed and it did for a while :

```
docker run -d -p 10051:10051 -p 10052:10052 -p 80:80 -p 2812:2812
--name zabbix-2 -v /var/lib/docker/volumes/b004ea515c677a31ab4063eb8785d025430f5871a4c1e7746d509d84a1d11213/_data:/usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts
-v
```

But the problem is, when I do `docker inspect` I get :

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/392b47a797daad7280748bb2eb336c42233e677077eb2d0f8c9b4ed988009a72/_data",
                "Destination": "/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
```

so somehow it quickly got overwritten.

Is there any way of mounting the other volume (that was once made for another container) to this one?

I tried copying the data in /var/lib/ of the old container to a new dir and mount it that way ...  I see this when I do `docker inspect`.

```
  {
                "Source": "/var/lib/data/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/mysql",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
```

which is good but the database is not coming up.

Comment: Not positive, but I would think that polluting the docker directory like this is not ideal.    What if you copied the data elsewhere, then map it.

Comment: @user2105103: I did that but it didn't work. the problem is a mysql data volume

Comment: "Not coming up" is insufficient.  Logs, errors?

Comment: I fixed it. There was a ownership issue with the volume. `/var/lib/data/_data` was owned by root so mysql couldn't access it.

Comment: but my dashboard still has no data in it @user2105103 hmm

Comment: At this point it might just be zabbix/mysql issues vs docker. But it looks like that volume mount didn't really do much.